# Search for specific characters in specific positions of line

Tags: linux, shell

I'm fairly new in linux world and i need your help. 
i need a code to search for specific characters in spcific positions in a text file.
i.e

The file sequences.txt looks like this:

```
ACGTCAGTCAG**T**CAGCATC**G**ATCGACTACGACCGTAGCTAGCTATACGACT**G**ATCAGCTACGATCAGCTACGATCAGCTACGAT
ACGTCAGTCAG**A**CAGCATC**C**ATCGACCATGCTAGCCGTACGATTAGCGACT**C**ATCAGCTACGATCAGCTACGATCAGCTACGAT
ACGTCAGTCAG**T**CAGCATCATCGACTACGACTACGATCGATCGATCGGACT**G**ATCAGCTACGATCAGCTACGATCAGCTACGATG
ACGTCAGTCAG**A**CAGCATC**G**ATCGACTACGACGATCGATCGATCTACGACT**C**ATCAGCTACGATCAGCTACGATCAGCTACGAT
```

What i want is to split the dataset in different output files grouping the equal lines containing the same specific charactrs.

hope someone can help me,
all the best

Comment: So how should your desired output look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for "foo" at position 42:

```
egrep '^.{42}foo'
```

You can run a command like this multiple times on your input:

```
egrep '^.{42}foo' inputfile.txt > lineswithfoo.txt
egrep '^.{42}bar' inputfile.txt > lineswithbar.txt
...
```

or as a loop:

```
for pattern in foo bar qux; do
  egrep "^.{42}$pattern" inputfile.txt > lineswith$pattern.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk`s substring operations might be useful here. Something along these lines:

```
awk '{ x=substr($0, 42, 3); print > "output" x ".txt"}'
```

This would take the 3-character substring of each line starting at position 42 (0-based indexing, remember), and form an output file name "outputXYZ.txt" from that substring, and then append that line to it.